# How to calculate pi-type impedance matching circuit?

Tags: wifi

The value provided in the first schematic L=2.7nH, C15=2.0pF, C14=2.7pF, how they will get these values. If I want to design an impedance matching circuit for the same (30+j10) ohm, what process I will follow? it's Related to ESP32 antenna.
Sorry for incomplete information.
I want, how to design PI- type impedance matching circuits.

- operating frequency: 2.4 GHz
- input impedance: (35+j10) ohm
- output impedance: 50 ohm

Comment: I no see schematic

Comment: Use this: https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/interactive-design-tools/rf-impedance-matching-calculator.html

Comment: See here (with examples): Chris Bowick, "RF Circuit Design". "Chapter 4: Impedance matching". Section "Three-element matching". Subsection "The Pi Network" (pdf of older edition can be found in web)

Answer (score 1):

You have three "unknowns" — the three component values.

You have three "knowns" — the operating frequency, the required input impedance and the required output impedance.

You just need to set up the three simultaneous equations and solve them — it's simple algebra.

This paper goes into a lot more detail, including considerations of bandwidth: [Improving the Bandwidth of Simple Matching Networks](https://www.highfrequencyelectronics.com/Mar08/HFE0308_Tutorial.pdf)